# Issue with if (mb_strlen() != #)

Tags: php, conditional-statements

This is probably really dirty and messy code, so any input on that would be helpful as well, but my main issue is that I can't get the "ISBN" input to process if the string is the correct number of characters (10 or 13). I'm not sure where it is going wrong. It's on line 64.

Please help! Thank you.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Link Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php

        function showForm() {

            if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
                $title = "Book Title";
            } else {
                $title = $_POST['title'];
            }
    ?>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

        Search by ISBN<br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="13" name="ISBN" size="30" value="ISBN" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='ISBN'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'ISBN') {this.value=''}" /><br />

        <br />OR<br /><br />

        Search by Title <strong>and</strong> Author<br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="13" name="title" size="30" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Book Title'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Book Title') {this.value=''}" /><br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="13" name="aname" size="30" value="Author Name" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Author Name'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Author Name') {this.value=''}" /><br />

        <br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Link" />

    </form>

    <?php

        }

        function generateLink_ISBN() {
            echo "Your link has been generated:<br />";
            echo "http://xxx.com/uhtbin/cgisirsi.exe/x/0/0/5?search_type=search&searchdata1=" . $_POST['ISBN'] . "&library=ALL&sort_by=PBYR";   
        }

        function generateLink_title() {
            echo "Your link has been generated:<br />";
            echo "http://xxx.com/uhtbin/cgisirsi.exe/x/0/0/5?search_type=search&searchdata1=" . $_POST['title'] . "+" . $_POST['aname'] . "&library=ALL&sort_by=PBYR";  
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if (isset($_POST['ISBN']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['aname']) && ($_POST['ISBN'] == 'ISBN') && ($_POST['aname'] == 'Author Name') && ($_POST['title'] == 'Book Title')) {

                echo "<h1>You did not input any information</h1>";
                showForm();

            } elseif (isset($_POST['ISBN']) && ($_POST['ISBN'] != 'ISBN')) {

                if (isset($_POST['ISBN']) && ($_POST['ISBN'] != 'ISBN') && (!is_numeric ($_POST['ISBN']))) {

                     echo "<h1>The ISBN you entered did not contain all numerics</h1>";
                     showForm();

                } elseif (isset($_POST['ISBN']) && ($_POST['ISBN'] != 'ISBN') && ((mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') != 13) | (mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') != 10))) {

                    echo "<h1>The ISBN you entered was too long or too short. ISBN's are 10 or 13 numbers in length.</h1>";
                    showForm();

                } else  {

                    generateLink_ISBN();

                }

            } elseif (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['aname']) && ($_POST['aname'] != 'Author Name') | ($_POST['title'] != 'Book Title')) {

                if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['aname']) && ($_POST['title'] == 'Book Title') && ($_POST['aname'] != 'Author Name')) {

                    echo "<h1>To search by author's name, you must also include the book title.</h1>";
                    showForm();

                } elseif (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['aname']) && ($_POST['aname'] == 'Author Name') && ($_POST['title'] != 'Book Title')) {

                    echo "<h1>To search by book title, you must also include the author's name.</h1>";
                    showForm();

                } else {

                    generateLink_title();

                }

            } else {

                showForm(); 

            }

        } else {

            showForm(); 

        }

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Since you asked for input on your code:  Do whatever you can to separate processing and the presentation.  I like to use templating systems for this like Smarty.  If that's too big of a production, consider preparing your form in one file and displaying it with another.  It makes life a lot easier when you know you can change the logic without wading through/breaking the interface.  Also, don't forget to validate the data from the POST.  Assume users are evil.  :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new at php, how would I validate it? And in this case, I don't think it will be necessary because its merely generating a link to a search query?

Comment: @jmalais Correct. The validation you perform above should be adequate for generating a link - the web service you call out to should be validating their inputs as well, so the worst that is likely to happen is you generate a bad link cause the user gave you bad data. In general though, it's a good idea to validate, if nothing else just to stop your script from bombing if it makes an assumption about inputs. Take a look at the PHP filter documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always evaluates to true:

```
((mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') != 13) | (mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') != 10))
```

You're saying "if ISBN isn't 13 characters long or ISBN isn't 10 characters long, then true". But no string can be both 13 characters and 10 characters.

Try this instead:

```
!((mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') == 13) | (mb_strlen($_POST['ISBN'], 'utf-8') == 10))
```

Which would be "if it is not the case that either ISBN is 13 characters or ISBN is 10 characters, then true".

Comment: @jmalais Great! Since it worked, you should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it! :)

Comment: Yeah no worries, I was going to earlier but had to wait and got a little preoccupied with the finishing touches.